Book/novel about a girl who lives in the human world and finds out she's a fairy princess whose parents are the king and queen of the fairies' realm
I’ve been trying to search for this novel that I remember reading years ago.
It’s about a girl who lives in the human world. She has a best friend and a boyfriend. She then finds out that she is a fairy princess whose parents are the king and queen of the fairies' realm. I remember reading that she portaled back and forth between the human world and the fairies' world. In the human world, she has a child with her boyfriend.
That’s all I can remember. Please if anyone can help me find this novel, I’ll be so happy!!

In roughly which year did you read this? And do you recall anything about the cover?

This is a really common plot in fantasy books. Without some extra clues it's going to be hard to find the book. Is there nothing else you can remember? Character names or place names or any memorable events in the book?
